# Set default syntax to different filetype in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext

How do I set a default filetype for a certain file extension in Sublime Text 2?  Specifically I want to have *.cfg files default to having Ini syntax highlighting but I cannot seem to figure out how I could create this custom setting.

Answer (score 1631, accepted):

In the current version of Sublime Text 2 (Build: 2139), you can set the syntax for all files of a certain file extension using an option in the menu bar. Open a file with the extension you want to set a default for and navigate through the following menus: `View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... ->[your syntax choice]`.

**Updated 2012-06-28:** Recent builds of Sublime Text 2 (at least since Build 2181) have allowed the syntax to be set by clicking the current syntax type in the lower right corner of the window. This will open the syntax selection menu with the option to `Open all with current extension as...` at the top of the menu.

**Updated 2016-04-19:** As of now, this also works for Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Did you try `Open all with current extension as...` or just setting the syntax via a choice in the `Syntax` menu?

Comment: Confirmed. You need to restart Sublime for the changes to stick. Also, this doesn't change the "active" file - you can tell by looking in the bottom right at the syntax it has chosen. Restarting fixes it though.

Comment: Can this be done on a per-project basis? For example, for one project, I might want Mako syntax for .html files; while another might use another syntax.

Comment: This is still the method used in ST3 (as of build 3010). No restart seems to be required, and all active files with the extension are updated automatically.

Comment: @tb. In my ST3, all choices are disabled (grey)

Comment: @ziyuang - Make sure you have the cursor somewhere in the open file.

Comment: @ziyuang, the files you're editing need to have a file extension.

Comment: Supplementary question: how do I get files named `build`, even those with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, **not** to default to `NAnt Build File` formatting?

Comment: How can I achieve the same with files without extensions (e.g. `Makefile`)? I can't modify the contents of it also, as suggested in another answer.

Comment: so many years I used to set it by hands, and so easy it was to set it authomatically ))

Answer (score 150):

Go to a `Packages/User`, create (or edit) a `.sublime-settings` file named after the Syntax where you want to add the extensions, `Ini.sublime-settings` in your case, then write there something like this:

```
{
    "extensions":["cfg"]
}
```

And then restart Sublime Text

Comment: N.B. The syntax you want to use is case sensitive (e.g. `CSS` for css) and this will override setting it via the UI (see @Colin's post)

Comment: @Elland I [opened an issue](https://github.com/braindamageinc/SublimeHttpRequester/issues/6) for the problem.

Comment: I find it easier with sublime text 2/3, to open your file, then select the syntax you want to use.
Then click Preferences-> Settings - More -> Syntax Specific - User.
And it will create that file for you. Just paste the above code in, save, and restart.

Comment: Used this way because I was able to remove a settings file that was overriding my settings via the UI

Comment: Is there any way to configure this for a particular project?

Comment: NOTE: If your files have double extensions (such as `some_page.html.erb` in Ruby on Rails), make sure to add `{"extensions": ["html.erb"]}`—just adding `["erb"]` at least currently does not work.

Comment: This works great in Sublime 3 for scss.liquid files (files with double extensions). I added SCSS.sublime-settings with content: {"extensions": ["scss.liquid"]} and wammo bammo. It's pretty!

Answer (score 21):

In ST2 there's a package you can install called Default FileType which does just that.

More info [here](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-DefaultFileType).

Comment: `This package sets the default file type of new files to be either the same as the current file, or a predefined default.`  Exactly what I Was looking for! Thanks

Comment: in ST3, it also works! just need some manual work (save DefaultFileType in ST3 user path.

Answer (score 5):

You can turn on syntax highlighting based on the contents of the file.

For example, my Makefiles regardless of their extension the first line as follows:

```
#-*-Makefile-*- vim:syntax=make
```

This is typical practice for other editors such as vim.

However, for this to work you need to modify the 
`Makefile.tmLanguage` file.

1. Find the file (for Sublime Text 3 in Ubuntu) at:

   ```
   /opt/sublime_text/Packages/Makefile.sublime-package
   ```

Note, that is really a zip file. Copy it, rename with .zip at the end, and extract the Makefile.tmLanguage file from it.

2. Edit the new `Makefile.tmLanguage` by adding the "firstLineMatch" key and string after the "fileTypes" section. In the example below, the last two lines are new (should be added by you). The `<string>` section holds the regular expression, that will enable syntax highlighting for the files that match the first line. This expression recognizes two patterns: "`-*-Makefile-*-`" and "`vim:syntax=make`".

   ```
   ...
   <key>fileTypes</key>
   <array>
       <string>GNUmakefile</string>
       <string>makefile</string>
       <string>Makefile</string>
       <string>OCamlMakefile</string>
       <string>make</string>
   </array>

   <key>firstLineMatch</key>
   <string>^#\s*-\*-Makefile-\*-|^#.*\s*vim:syntax=make</string>
   ```
3. Place the modified `Makefile.tmLanguage` in the User settings directory:

   ```
   ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Makefile.tmLanguage
   ```

All the files matching the first line rule should turn the syntax highlighting on when opened.

Comment: This was helpful. Nice to know it's possible, but editing every .sublime-package file for each file type that might contain such a pattern is not practical. Therefore, I probably won't use this feature.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution for me turned out to be to used the [ApplySyntax package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ApplySyntax).

The steps are as follows:

1. Install the package via Package Control
2. `CTRL + SHIFT + P` and enter `ApplySyntax: Browse Syntaxes`. Find your desired syntax here and note the exact line shown, e.g. I was looking to set it to Markdown from the Markdown Editing package, so for me the line was `MarkdownEditing/syntaxes/Markdown`.
3. `CTRL + SHIFT + P` and enter `ApplySyntax: Settings`.
4. On line `"new_file_syntax": "XYZ"`, enter the line from Step 2.

See [here](https://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax/usage/) for further documentation.

I found this to work better than the [DefaultFileType package](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-DefaultFileType), because it isn't limited to just new files created by pressing `CTRL + N` and captured new tabs opened by clicking the empty space to the right of an open tab.

I hope is useful to someone 11 years after the original question was asked.