# How to customise file type to syntax associations in Sublime Text?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I'd like Sublime 2 editor to treat *.sbt files (to highlight syntax) as Scala language, same as *.scala, but I can't find where to set this up. Do you happen to know?

Comment: It's a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7574502/1346682

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default syntax to different filetype in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574502/set-default-syntax-to-different-filetype-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 1315, accepted):

In Sublime Text (confirmed in both v2.x and v3.x) there is a menu command:

> View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as ...

Comment: do you have any idea how this is reflected in the sublime text config files? I'm trying to achieve this with an automated chef recipe and I can't figure out what to set in the settings JSON.

Comment: @brad Open syntax specific settings (Scala.sublime-settings in Users folder), and add to them:

{ "extensions":
["scala",
"sbt"]}

Comment: Yet another command misteriously absent from the command palette (ctrl/cmd-shift-P)

Comment: Also doesn't work as expected for filenames with double extension. Editing the `*.sublime-settings` *does* work.

Comment: How do you set a default syntax for files opened that have no extension?

Comment: Finally! How annoying I couldnt find this until now, had been fiddling around with an extension as suggested in another answer.

Comment: And what do you do when this whole menu is greyed out / lists everything but is entirely unselectable?

Answer (score 42):

I've found the answer (by further examining the Sublime 2 config files structure):

I was to open

```
~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Scala/Scala.tmLanguage
```

And edit it to add `sbt` (the extension of files I want to be opened as Scala code files) to the array after the `fileTypes` key:

```
<dict>
  <key>bundleUUID</key>
  <string>452017E8-0065-49EF-AB9D-7849B27D9367</string>
  <key>fileTypes</key>
  <array>
    <string>scala</string>
    <string>sbt</string>
  <array>
  ...
```

PS: May there be a better way, something like a right place to put my customizations (insted of modifying packages themselves), I'd still like to know.

Comment: it's now in ```/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Scala/Scala.tmLanguage```

Comment: I think is the user library rather than the system library: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Scala/Scala.tmLanguage`

Comment: @Eric, you should read more careful.. It opens all files with that specific extension with the specified syntax. Most of the time, this is what you want.

Answer (score 29):

I put my customized changes in the User package:

```
*nix: ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/Scala.tmLanguage
*Windows: %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\Scala.tmLanguage
```

Which also means it's in JSON format:

```
{
  "extensions":
  [
    "sbt"
  ]
}
```

This is the same place the

```
View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as ...
```

menu item adds it (creating the file if it doesn't exist).

Comment: Note that this is the only method (at least in ST2) that allows to set specific syntax for files with double extensions (for example, `whatever.twig.html`), as the menu method only takes the last one!

Comment: I found this works with Sublime Text 3. I used `View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as ...` to create the language file `Markdown.sublime-settings` in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/`, and then edited this file to add extra file extensions.

Answer (score 19):

For ST3

`$language = "language u wish"`

If exists, open `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/*$language*.sublime-settings`

else just create it.

And set

```json
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "*yourextension*"
    ]
}
```

This way allows you to enable syntax for composite extensions (e.g. sql.mustache, js.php, etc ... )

Comment: So to associate .js.php files with JavaScript, I should create a file called Javascript.sublime-settings filled with `{ "extensions": [ "js.php" ] }` ?

Comment: Yes if the file not exists, if already exists just add the extension you desire on "extensions" array.

Comment: ST now has a menu item for this: `Settings` > `Settings -- Syntax Specific`.

Answer (score 14):

There's an excellent plugin called [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) (previously DetectSyntax) that provides certain other niceties for file-syntax matching. allows regex expressions etc.

Answer (score 14):

There is a quick method to set the syntax:
`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`,then type in the input box

> ss  + （which type you want set）

eg:  ss html +`Enter`

and **ss** means "set syntax"

it is really quicker than check in the menu's checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

I know this topic is old now, but let me state a new approach, some people might find this easy to understand and do.

Open Sublime Text(make sure you have **Package Control** [installed and ready](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) in your Sublime Text):

1. **Ctrl+Shift+P**(or **Cmd+Shift+P** for MacOS guys)
2. Type "PRV"(Package Resource Viewer), select the one ending with `:Open Resource`
3. Type "SCALA"/"scala" and press Enter
4. Type `Scala.sublime-syntax` and press Enter and press Esc to close the
   open list
5. Now in `Scala.sublime-syntax` goto the section `file_extensions:` and add your file extension `sbt`(like `- sbt`) in the end of that section
6. Save and close the file and restart Sublime Text, you'll now have
   `Scala` syntax highlighting for your custom `.sbt` extension. Same steps can be done with any file type like `XML`, `PHP`, `HTML`, `JS` etc.

Pretty easy to follow, right ?