# Changing the Handlebars extensions in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, templates, express, handlebars.js

[Handlebars template's filename extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196191/handlebars-templates-filename-extension)

Hi,
my templates files got the extension `.handlebars` and I want to change it to `.hbs`

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'index'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

when changing `handlebars` to `hbs` and renaming the files, errors appear. The files are not found anymore.

What is missing?

Comment: [How to change handlebars extension for express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580640/how-to-change-handlebars-extension-for-express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the following properties

```
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
const handlebars = exphbs.create({
  // layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'app/views/layouts'),
  // partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'app/views/partials'),
  defaultLayout: 'index',
  extname: 'hbs'
});

app.engine('hbs', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code something like this:

`

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname : 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'index', layoutsDir: __dirname+'/views/layouts'}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Change your file's extentions from 
`.hanlebars`
to 
`.hbs` and put your `index.hbs` file inside `path/to/project/views/layouts` and rest of the `.hbs` file should remain in `path/to/project/views/`.

Comment: this is really annoying, the main file `index` should be placed above the other template files instead of below