# How to customize file type '*.react.js' to syntax associations in Sublime Text?

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext, jsx

Right now on the project we use **.react.js* as type extension for JSX files for some reasons.

Is it possible in Sublime Text add custom file extension with **.react.js* pattern (i.e. using dot sign in the extension)?

I know that it's possible write py script to handle it, but maybe I missed something in settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customise file type to syntax associations in Sublime Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088475/how-to-customise-file-type-to-syntax-associations-in-sublime-text)

Comment: @idleberg, no, because here I'm asking about custom extension that contains dot (i.e. _.react.js_)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I think it solves your problem. ST has the [babel](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime) extension, which works great for JSX and JS files alike. You could use that for all files with `.js` extension and I think you'll be good.

Another reason not to go down the extension rabbit hole is that these days it's recommended that JSX files end in `.js`, making it even harder to differentiate. But Babel highlighter solves all.