# Double Filetype Extension: Correct Syntax Highlighting in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am working with some `.scss.liquid` files and they always open as HTML Liquid, no matter how many times I set the syntax.

**Update:**

I tried ***open all with current extension as*** option, but unfortunately this affects files that are `.js.liquid` and `.html.liquid` as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customise file type to syntax associations in Sublime Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088475/how-to-customise-file-type-to-syntax-associations-in-sublime-text)

Comment: Especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12901082/2348587) where the comment notes that it works with double extensions

Comment: Thanks @DarrickHerwehe, the answer is indeed buried as a comment to one of the non-accepted answers on that question's page. My suggestion is to create a more accessible answer here as my Google fu is good and I didn't find that before. Clearly having a more specific question and answer here would be beneficial to the community. Please feel free to provide the canonical answer to the double filetype extension issue here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sublime Text allows you to apply settings on a per-language basis (actually, per syntax). One of the available settings allows you to map file extensions to the given syntax.

Assuming you're using a syntax named `SCSS`, Create an SCSS settings file in your User settings: `/path/to/packages/User/SCSS.sublime-settings`, then add the file extension setting:

```
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "scss.liquid"
    ]
}
```

As you can see, it's a json file, and `extensions` is a list, so you can add as many file extensions as you need. Do not add the leading dot.

#### Caveat about the file name

The file name for the settings file *must* match the actual syntax name, including case. In this case it has to be `SCSS.sublime-settings`. Other examples include:

```
NAnt Build File.sublime-settings
Ruby on Rails.sublime-settings
Rd (R Documentation).sublime-settings
Java Server Page (JSP).sublime-settings
```

Comment: I had trouble figuring this out, and figured out an easy way to do it. Here, I made a movie https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYESRD8O0Bw

Answer (score 0):

I found a relatively straightforward solution to this problem.

1. Install [ApplySyntax](http://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax/installation/)
2. Create the following rules in `ApplySyntax.sublime-settings -- User`:

   ```
   "syntaxes": [
       {
           "syntax": "SCSS",
           "extensions": ["scss.liquid"]
       },
       {
           "syntax": "JavaScript/JavaScript",
           "extensions": ["js.liquid"]
       },
   ]
   ```

**Update**: I now see there is no need for an extra package. Please see accepted answer and my video (in the comments) for tips on how to make it work.