# How to ERB Snippet package make working.

Tags: sublimetext3, erb

I use the SublimeText3. I have installed the ERB Snippet package to have ability to use `if, if-else, end, etc` snippets into html.erb files.
But into ST3 when I try to open `foo.html.erb` file it always is opened with ERB, not HTML(Rails) view. By default ERB Snippet works only into `text.html.ruby` scope, so to make it run I need for each opened `html.erb` file to use 'Open all with current extension', which is annoying.

So the questions are:

1. Is it possible to figure out ST3 to open `html.erb` with HTML(Rails) view instead of ERB?
2. Or is it possible to figure out ERB Snippets to work with ERB scope?

Comment: Not yet, because this issue is related with double file extension, i.e. html.erb, not just erb. As I found, this double extension is not correctly supported now into ST3.

Comment: that is covered under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12901082/2348587) on that question. Someone asked it as a [top level question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495487/double-filetype-extension-correct-syntax-highlighting-in-sublime-text-3) last week as well because he felt that answer was buried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double Filetype Extension: Correct Syntax Highlighting in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495487/double-filetype-extension-correct-syntax-highlighting-in-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score -1):

I found the dirty solution. I just edited scope into all ERB Snippets(`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/ERB Snippets`) from `text.html.ruby` to `text.html.erb`. So now the `html.erb` is still opened with ERB view but snippets work.