# Make HTML syntax default for Handlebars (.hbs) files in SublimeText3

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, sublimetext3

Every time I open an **hbs** file in Sublime Text 3, I should go to `View>Syntax>HTML` to change the syntax view. How can I make it automatic or default in Sublime?

Comment: Go to  `View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as ...`  and select 'HTML' option.                                                                                                     Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088475/how-to-customise-file-type-to-syntax-associations-in-sublime-text

Comment: This question is off-topic. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sublime Text (confirmed in both v2.x and v3.x) there is a menu command:

> View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as ...

Form [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088475/how-to-customise-file-type-to-syntax-associations-in-sublime-text) Answered by TedG (Edited byAir)