# Recognize internal files as JSON

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

What's the way to tell Sublime automatically open it's own files, i.e.

- `.sublime-settings`
- `.sublime-keymap`
- `.sublime-theme`
- etc.

as JSON-files? (I mean, with proper syntax highlighting).

Comment: In which Operating System?

Comment: @jeprubio Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customise file type to syntax associations in Sublime Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088475/how-to-customise-file-type-to-syntax-associations-in-sublime-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case I‘d recommend installing [PackageDev](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageDev). Generally, you can configure to [always assign a specific syntax](https://superuser.com/questions/1198407/how-to-get-sublime-text-3-to-automatically-highlight-cshtml-as-html/1198446#1198446) to a file type.