# Sublime Text 3 - Set Default “Plain Text” to HTML?

Tags: sublimetext3

I want the default sublime text 3 file type from "Plain Text" to HTML. I installed Default file type and added this:

```
"default_new_file_syntax": "Packages/HTML/HTML.tmLanguage",
"use_current_file_syntax": true
```

to the settings. What is wrong?

Comment: _This only affects files which are created with the Ctrl+N shortcut (Cmd+N on OSX)_.

Comment: Is it possible to set default sublime text 3 file type from "Plain Text" to HTML?

Comment: I think it's determined by file extension when you start sublime... Or by that package but only when you create file with `Ctrl + N`.

Comment: If I'd like to set all txt files to HTML? Impossible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8088475/9871463 can this help ?  It's christmass and I'm not on computer, sorry. See comments on first answer