# assign file extension to color scheme in Sublime 2

Tags: sublimetext

How can I link `.scss` files to be automatically use css color scheme?

Comment: This question was asked in a slightly different form (eg, with a different extension) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574502/set-default-syntax-to-different-filetype-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

The first way is to open a css file and then go to `Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User` to open a file called `CSS.sublime-settings`. add the following code there:

```
{ "extensions": [ "scss"] }
```

The second way to do this is to click on the file-type button in the bottom right corner of the editor (on the status bar). At the top of the menu you'll find `Open all with current extension as...` click on it and then choose css from the list (This will basically add the same code as above to your css.sublime-settings file).