# Sublime Text open *.handlebars.coffee as HTML file

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm trying to configure Sublime Text 2 to open up *.handlebars.coffee files using HTML syntax highlighting as a default. I know that I can change the default syntax highlighting for all .coffee files, but is there a way to change the defaults for a file with two extensions?

I've seen this similar post but this does not quite answer my question:
[Set default syntax to different filetype in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574502/set-default-syntax-to-different-filetype-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add *handlebars.coffee* to the fileTypes array in HTML.tmLanguage.  After I did that, Sublime opened an example *handlebars.coffee* file as html syntax.  Here's the relevant lines from my HTML.tmLanguage file:

```
<key>fileTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>handlebars.coffee</string>
    <string>html</string>
    <string>htm</string>
    etc.
</array>
```

You can access this file by opening the HTML folder under *preferences > browse packages...*

Make sure to save a **new** version of this file in your *User* preference folder.  This will retain it through updates.

Comment: I tried this with coffee.haml and this did not work - perhaps because a haml package already exists and beats this to the punch?