# apply syntax highlighting to files with undefined extension

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

I'm opening .RUL files in Sublime Text which do not have any syntax highlighting, since InstallScript has a similar syntax to C/C++ I want all my .rul files to be treated as if they were .c or .cpp files and automatically have all the same highlighting applied to them. In other words: I want to have the same effect as if I renamed each .rul file to .cpp and then opened the .cpp in Sublime.

What's the easiest way to implement this in Sublime Text 2.0.2 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set default syntax to different filetype in Sublime Text 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574502/set-default-syntax-to-different-filetype-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the other solutions posted above will apply to all future instances of *.rul files, OR only to the currently open file.

I found a solution that works perfectly fine for me, just edit:
...\Application Data\Sublime Text 2\Packages\C++\C.tmLanguage

```
<key>fileTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>c</string>
    <string>h</string>
    <string>rul</string>
```

According to:
http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-2/reference/syntaxdefs.html

*fileTypes*

```
This is a list of file extensions (without the leading dot). When opening files of these types, Sublime Text will automatically activate this syntax definition for them. Optional.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can open the file in Sublime Text and use menu "View" → "Syntax" → "Open all with current extension as..." → (select appropriate syntax).

Also, you can click on right bottom corner of the window. This will open similar menu, where "Open all with current extension as..." is presented too.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `C++`, highlight `Set Syntax: C++` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Or go to `View` menu > `Syntax` > Click `C++`.

Answer (score 0):

/Users/HOME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/C++/C++.sublime-settings

```
{
    "extensions": ["cpp", "cc", "cxx", "c++", "h", "hpp", "hxx", "h++", "inl", "ipp", "rul"]
}
```

---

Or, create a similar file and place it in your `User` directory, for `rul` and any other additional extensions *not* defined in the file mentioned hereinabove:

/Users/HOME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/C++.sublime-settings

```
{
    "extensions": ["rul"]
}
```