# How to syntax-highlight HTML inside JavaScript strings in Sublime

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

Is there any Sublime package to syntax-highlight HTML inside JavaScript strings?

*(Note the question is only about HTML inside JS strings, not syntax highlighting in general.)*

Specifically I am writing Angular components using inline templates

```
angular.module('compMod', []).component('myComp', {
    template: `<div>Some Text</div>`
});
```

and looking to highlight HTML syntax inside the ES6 template strings.

Comment: I don't know if there's a package like that, but I feel like it's not a good idea anyway. You probably want things inside template strings to be highlighted properly when it's not HTML. You could, however, use `templateUrl` and link to a template file instead of using a template string.

Comment: @Calvin There is an advantage to inline templates to have everything in one place, it is frequently used, e.g. [here](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/blob/master/src/directives/formly-form.js), but as far as I know the author of that package uses Webstorm which does exactly that.

Comment: Open an [issue](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues) in sublimehq's Packages repo on Github and make a request using the `[JavaScript]` tag. In the latest version of `JavaScript.sublime-syntax`, template strings in backticks are marked as such, so it shouldn't be too difficult to import the HTML syntax there. They may or may not agree, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I answered the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160260/html-syntax-highlight-sublime-3-typescript/

Answer (score 12):

As @Calvin commented above, I wouldn't say this is a good practice, yet I wouldn't necessarily say it's entirely bad one. Anyways, here's my naive solution (haven't tested it for any edge cases):

Install [babel package for sublime text](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel) and choose it as the [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574502/set-default-syntax-to-different-filetype-in-sublime-text-2) syntax for your your *.js files.

Next, edit `JavaScript (Babel).sublime-syntax`, which is located inside the Babel package directory, e.g. `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Babel/`.

Search for the section `template-string-body:`, and add at its beginning the following two lines, similar to @VRPF's suggestion:

```
- meta_content_scope: text.html.basic.embedded.js
- include: scope:text.html.basic
```

Now you have a full support in es6 + HTML syntax within template-strings.

Comment: This worked! If you want to achieve it with the default JavaScript syntax, you can use Package Resource Viewer -> Open Resource -> JavaScript -> JavaScript.sublime-syntax, and modify `literal-string-template`: Set `meta_scope` to `text.html.basic.embedded.js` and `include` to `scope:text.html.basic`.

Answer (score 4):

I would just create a new syntax highlighter as you dont have to worry if they update the normal packages.

Go to `Tools > Developer > New Syntax...`

```
%YAML 1.2
---
# See http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html
name: Javascript HTML
file_extensions:
  - element.js
  - tag.js
  - jsx
  - js
scope: source.js.tag
contexts:
  main:
    - match: ""
      push: Packages/JavaScript/JavaScript.sublime-syntax
      with_prototype:
      - match: '([a-zA-Z$_][\w$_]*)?(`)'
        push:
          - meta_content_scope: text.html.basic.embedded.js
          - include: 'scope:text.html.basic'
          - match: '`'
            pop: true
          - match: '\$\{'
            captures:
              0: punctuation.definition.template-expression.begin.js
            push:
              - meta_scope: meta.template.expression.js
              - include: 'scope:source.js'
              #- meta_content_scope: source.js.embedded.expression
              - match: '\}'
                scope: punctuation.definition.template-expression.end.js
                pop: true
```

Then save as  `JavascriptHTML.sublime-syntax`

`Restart Sublime` then you can go to `View > Syntax > Open all with this ext as > Javascript HTML`