# HTML syntax highlight sublime 3 Typescript

Tags: html, typescript, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I am using TypeScript with Sublime 3. How can I add HTML highlight in template attribute: [NOTE: I am already using Microsoft TypeScript Package]

Look how its not highlighted now:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read here how to achieve this:

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/javascript-es6-template-literals-syntax-for-html/18242

Reproduced here:

Open Tools > Developer > New Syntax

Add:

```
%YAML1.2
---
# See http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html
name: JavaScript NG
file_extensions:
  - js
  - ng.js
scope: source.js.ng
contexts:
  main:
    - match: ""
      push: scope:source.js
      with_prototype:
      - match: '`'
        push:
          - meta_content_scope: text.html.basic.embedded.js
          - include: 'scope:text.html.basic'
          - match: '`'
          pop: true
```

and save it has  JavaScript-NG.sublime-syntax

There is also an open github issue on this:

https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/179

Comment: I came across this article before posting the question. it did not do any highlighting. When it finishes loading the syntax everything is the same. I tried relaunching sublime but nothing happened.

Comment: I got it working after choosing 'Javascript NG' from view -> syntax -> 'Javascript NG'

Comment: I created a file name JavaScript-NG.sublime-syntax, pasted the content provided in this answer, saved it to packages>user. the restart sublime. But I couldn't activate the syntax in sublime.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a quick fix that still makes use of your installed `TypeScript` package and its existing syntax highlight definition:

1. Open a TypeScript file (with your installed TypeScript syntax highlighting)
2. Select *Tools > Developer > New Syntax from Typescript.tmLanguage* to create a new syntax definition file **based on the existing one**
3. Find the `template` context (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for `string.template.ts`) and add an include for `'scope:text.html.basic'`  to the `push` as indicated in the **commented** line below:

   ```YAML
   %YAML 1.2
   ---
   # http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html
   name: TypeScript + HTML  # <-- renaming is optional

     # ...

     template:
       - match: "([_$[:alpha:]][_$[:alnum:]]*)?(`)"
         captures:
           1: entity.name.function.tagged-template.ts
           2: punctuation.definition.string.template.begin.ts
         push:
           - meta_scope: string.template.ts
           - match: "`"
             captures:
               0: punctuation.definition.string.template.end.ts
             pop: true
           - include: template-substitution-element
           - include: string-character-escape
           - include: 'scope:text.html.basic'  # <-- !! only add this line !!
     template-substitution-element:

     # ...
   ```

   *optional step:*
   Change the `name` property at the beginning of the file to something like `TypeScript + HTML` to easily find and select it in the *Syntax* list later
4. Save the file with a `.sublime-syntax` file-ending
5. Restart Sublime Text and apply your new syntax highlighting to a typescript file:

   [image: Screenshot of HTML syntax highlighting inside Angular template string within a TypeScript file]

Comment: View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as > TypeScript + HTML :)

Comment: Any suggestions on getting this working with the inline css styles angular has as well?