HTML syntax highlighting inside of template-strings in Sublime Text
In Sublime Text I would like my javascript files to have HTML syntax highlighting inside of template-strings. Until yesterday, I was using a custom syntax I found from this stack overflow which looked like this:
%YAML 1.2
---
# See http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html
name: Javascript HTML
file_extensions:
  - element.js
  - tag.js
  - jsx
  - js
scope: source.js.tag
contexts:
  main:
    - match: ""
      push: Packages/JavaScript/JavaScript.sublime-syntax
      with_prototype:
      - match: '([a-zA-Z$_][\w$_]*)?(`)'
        push:
          - meta_content_scope: text.html.basic.embedded.js
          - include: 'scope:text.html.basic'
          - match: '`'
            pop: true
          - match: '\$\{'
            captures:
              0: punctuation.definition.template-expression.begin.js
            push:
              - meta_scope: meta.template.expression.js
              - include: 'scope:source.js'
              #- meta_content_scope: source.js.embedded.expression
              - match: '\}'
                scope: punctuation.definition.template-expression.end.js
                pop: true

I updated sublime last night and it threw an error saying "Apparent recursion within a with_prototype action: 25000 context sanity limit hit."
I now somewhat understand why this error throws and so started to look at the docs to write a new version that doesn't use with_prototype. I tried many things but I can never seem to get both JS highlighting and HTML within template-strings. It seems to only do one or the other.
After several attempts and my limited knowledge in this area I concluded that I should:

extend javascript
use meta_append to make my contexts apply after the original one

So this is the version of the syntax I've landed on but this still does not highlight html inside of template-strings and I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong.
%YAML 1.2
---
name: JavaScript HTML
file_extensions:
  - js
scope: source.js
version: 2
extends: Packages/JavaScript/JavaScript.sublime-syntax
contexts:
  main:
    - match: '(`)'
    - meta_append: true
      scope: punctuation.definition.string.begin.js
      push: template-literal

  template-literal:
    - meta_append: true
    - meta_scope: string.quoted.template.js
    - match: '`'
      scope: punctuation.definition.string.end.js
      pop: true
    
    - match: '(?=<)'
      embed: scope:text.html.basic
      embed_scope: text.html.basic
      escape: '(?=`)'

    - match: '\$\{'
      scope: punctuation.definition.template-expression.begin.js
      push:
        - meta_scope: meta.template.expression.js
        - include: Packages/JavaScript/JavaScript.sublime-syntax
        - match: '\}'
          scope: punctuation.definition.template-expression.end.js
          pop: true

Any thoughts or direction appreciated. I will keep playing and update if I get anywhere.
Update:
After playing some more today I decided to check the source of the Javascript.sublime-syntax. I realised if I simply make a context with the right name literal-string-template-begin and add my instructions there I should be able to get it working and so it's pretty crude but this does what I want now with the caveat that ${} don't get proper highlighting yet.
%YAML 1.2
---
name: JavaScript HTML
file_extensions:
  - js
scope: source.js
version: 2
extends: Packages/JavaScript/JavaScript.sublime-syntax
contexts:
  literal-string-template-begin:
    - match: '`'
      embed: scope:text.html.basic
      embed_scope: text.html.basic
      escape: '`'
      pop: true


See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230240/how-to-syntax-highlight-html-inside-javascript-strings-in-sublime can be of some help.
