# sublime text 4: how to add JSX syntax highlighting

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, sublimetext, sublimetext4

I have installed `sublime text 4`.

I have installed `babel-sublime` package inside sublime text.

BUt still i dont see the js files getting syntax highlighted

I still see

[image]

Comment: Does that happen with the JSX syntax that comes built in with ST4 ?

Comment: I found the soultion. `View > syntax > Open all with current extension as > javascript > JSX`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set default syntax to different filetype in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574502/set-default-syntax-to-different-filetype-in-sublime-text-2)